# How to create "NO HTTP" Server in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to know how to create a server in Nodejs to connect clients without the need of a browser. It is difficult to explain, but I mean if it is possible to create a server and also create a client application to connect directly between computers. **Attention, I do not want to create an http server.**

Comment: What are your options in terms of transport protocols? Why isn't HTTP one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe next sample that's you are looking for. I think you need use tcp instead http.

```
/*
TCP (net) Server
*/

var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

/*

$ netcat 127.0.0.1 1337

You should see:
> Echo server

*/

/* TCP (net) client */

var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server!');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.end(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: Is a perfect Option. I was basically looking for something similar to **tcp on c#**, Thanks. I can use this in an _electron_ app without problem.